# How to achieve precision on histogram plotting with GADFLY in JULIA

Tags: graph, julia, gadfly

I want to create a histogram which will display how many vertices  of different values are located in graph. I use Gadfly for plotting this histogram in language JULIA.

```
p = Gadfly.plot(x=int(array[1:end]), Geom.histogram, Theme(
 panel_fill=color("White"),
 panel_opacity=0.1,
 panel_stroke=color("Blue"),
               background_color=color("White")
                 # width of line
 ), Guide.ylabel("K core"),
 Guide.xlabel("Vertices"))
```

Code above plot histogram and after this i save it with another function to file as png format. The content of variable array is [1,1,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,3]

[image]

This is what I get after running this piece of code. Now the graph in this example has 8 vertices with value 3 and 2 vertices with value 1, and gadfly gives me histogram above. What is bothering me is the x-axis. I do not know why value 1 is displayed from 1 to 3 and value 3 from 3 to 5. I would like to make it more precise but does not know how. I tried a lot of variants and abbreviations of code but I am not able to get it working.

What I am looking for is that on  x-axis there would be values 1 and 3 and bars would not be so thick and it will be simpler to see that values are 1 and 3.

Any help ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to solve for about 4 hours and after posting question solved within 5 minutes :D

To make it more precise, everything that needs to be done is to add **Scale.x_discrete** to plot function after **Geom.histogram**.

```
p = Gadfly.plot(x=int(array[1:end]), Geom.histogram, Scale.x_discrete, Theme(
panel_fill=color("White"),
panel_opacity=0.1,
panel_stroke=color("Blue"),
           background_color=color("White")
             # width of line
), Guide.ylabel("K core"),
Guide.xlabel("Vertices"))
```

Now plot is more easily to read. Last thing is to order the array maybe so values on x-axis will be ordered.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Guide.xticks`](http://gadflyjl.org/guide_xticks.html) for that:

```
plot(x=rand(10), y=rand(10), Geom.line, Guide.xticks(ticks=ticks, orientation=:vertical))
```

Comment: I already came up to solution but thanks I will try just to find out what your solution does and how it is different:)